# How to get unique records on all columns

Tags: sql-server

```
Pro_Code  Pro_Name         Size1    Size2   Size3   Size4   Size5   Size6
P001      Shirt                 M   L   XL  XXl SS  S
P002    T-shirt                 M   L   XL  SS  S   M
P003    Formal                  M   L   SS  S   M   XL
```

Check the records in this table like Size1 have Multiple entry for M but if we want to fetch all sizes in a DropDownlist its should be show unique entry, like if size1 have multiple M entry but in a dropdown it should only one time M. and same for all size to size6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try DISTINCT [See examples](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/20/sql-server-distinct-keyword-usage-and-common-discussion/)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Size1  FROM TABLE
```

If you want all sizes together

```
SELECT Size1  FROM TABLE UNION
SELECT Size2  FROM TABLE UNION
SELECT Size3  FROM TABLE UNION
SELECT Size4  FROM TABLE UNION
SELECT Size5  FROM TABLE UNION
SELECT Size6  FROM TABLE
```

**EDIT**:

If you have Blanks in the column, to avoid blank.null columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT Size1  FROM TABLE where isnull(Size1,'')<>''
```

Comment: thanks, and please tell me how to remove blank entry if any column have blank

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

use DISTINCT

[SQL DISTINCT In Select query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)